# How to download images from url?

Tags: java, android

I want to download the image from reome URL and I get SSL error

```
 String imgURL="http://whootin.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/upload/0/0/23/82/Note_03_26_2013_01_10_55_68.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJF5QHW2P5ZLAGVDQ&Signature=Za4yG0YKS4%2FgoxSidFsZaAA8vWQ%3D&Expires=1364888750";

   final ImageView  ivCurrent;
   ivCurrent = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

  // calling DownloadAndReadImage class to load and save image in sd card

     DownloadAndReadImage dImage= new DownloadAndReadImage(imgURL,1);

     ivCurrent.setImageBitmap(dImage.getBitmapImage());
```

The error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x19a4a0: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: the 3000000000 question of that type. Did you even search here? Check the related questions at the right ->

Answer (score 1):

Your question make no sense because we know nothing about `DownloadAndReadImage` class, By the way I think you need to add these two permissions in your manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

***P.S If you are looking for a great `ImageLoder` library, I suggest you Android Universal Image Loader:***

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Perhaps the best is a big word, but I've added this library in several projects and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I download and store images in SD card using `InputStreams` in the following way:

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);

InputStream input = url.openStream();

try {

    // The sdcard directory e.g. '/sdcard' can be used directly, or
    // more safely abstracted with getExternalStorageDirectory()
    String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    .getAbsolutePath();

    int barIndex = imageUrl.indexOf("/");
    String path = imageUrl.substring(barIndex + 1) + ".jpg";

    String sdcardPath = storagePath + "/myapp/";

    File sdcardPathDir = new File(sdcardPath);

    sdcardPathDir.mkdirs();

    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(sdcardPath + imagemId + ".jpg");

    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } finally {
        output.close();
    }

} finally {
    input.close();
}
```

As @NullPointer pointed out, don't forget to check the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Connect to an HTTPS/HTTP URL via and the SSL certificate provided by the site is not trusted by the devise you are running the code on.

[setting up trust in the Apache HTTP Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https).